# How to authenticate login with firebase admin sdk with python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, kivy, firebase-admin

Is there any way by which I can make a user login using his email and password registered in my firebase authentication database?
I am using firebase admin SDK and kivy to make an app.

```
import self as self
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth

creds = credentials.Certificate('E:/Key/koronaksha_Key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(creds)
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        cols = 2
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        email_label = Label(text = 'Email')
        main_layout.add_widget(email_label)
        self.email_input = TextInput(multiline=False)
        main_layout.add_widget(self.email_input)
        pass_label = Label(text='Password')
        main_layout.add_widget(pass_label)
        self.pass_input = TextInput(password=True, multiline=False)
        main_layout.add_widget(self.pass_input)
        submit = Button(text='Submit',
                        size_hint=(.5, .1),
                        pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .1})
        submit.bind(on_press=self.on_press_button)
        main_layout.add_widget(submit)

        return main_layout

    def on_press_button(self, instance):
        print('You pressed the button!' + self.email_input.text + self.pass_input.text)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, you are very helpful, but I wanted the answer. It would help me a lot :D

Comment: Admin SDK should only be used in server-side applications. It doesn't support client-side operations like authenticating a user.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I wish there was a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not the SDK, but its works.

```
url = "%s?key=%s" % (__FIREBASE_USER_VERIFY_SERVICE, __FIREBASE_API_KEY)
data = {
    "email": request.data['email'],
    "password": request.data['password'],
    "returnSecureToken": True
}
result = requests.post(url, json=data)
if result.ok:
   token = auth.create_custom_token(user_rec['localId'])
   exp = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
   cookie = auth.create_session_cookie(user_rec['idToken'], expires_in=exp)
else:
    print('User %s fail to login')
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked but I shifted my whole project from python to HTML already :D