# Which Authentication worlflow for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, oauth

I'm starting a new project, and after testing my own JWT Auth, I think OAuth2 with an IdP like Firebase would be a better solution.

I found too much resources, butI'm now a bit confused.

- Firebase doc' : [Authenticating Users on App Engine Using Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine)
- Auth0 doc' : [Backend For Frontend Authentication Pattern with Auth0 and ASP.NET Core](https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/)
- Reddit : [Securing FastAPI with JWT Token-based Authentication](https://www.reddit.com/r/FastAPI/comments/10pzma3/securing_fastapi_with_jwt_tokenbased/)
- Stackoverflow : [The complete guide to protecting your APIs with OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/22/the-complete-guide-to-protecting-your-apis-with-oauth2/) (I couldn't find the part2?)
- Redis : [Client-side caching in Redis](https://redis.io/docs/manual/client-side-caching/)

**About my Project :**

- Frontend: Vue 3 (with Quasar) + Pinia
- Backend: FastAPI + firebase-admin
- Redis, PostgreSQL

**Side note:**
I think the `Diagram 1` make more sense, but I would like the advice of someone more experimented in oAuth. (pro/con of each diagram?)

I'm not familiar with Caching/Redis, but I read on the Auth0 Community, they recommended to cache the tokens, so the IdP will issue less tokens, and it will reduced the cost.

**Questions :**

- Which diagram/workflow would be the most secure and would you prefer ?
- I think it's possible to cache the tokens at the frontend level, but is it enough secure ?

[image: Diagram 1]

[image: Diagram 2]

Comment: Cache the access token from Firebase? Also, are you just adding Google sign in or so with any OAuth provider _along with Firebase_ in your app?

Comment: Can you explain the problem that you are trying to solved here instead of any other solutions (just a OAuth flow)? Also please answer the 2nd question in my previous comment?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I was looking at the auth0 thread : 
- [Thread 1](https://community.auth0.com/t/can-auth0-cache-requests-for-access-tokens/83346/5)
- [Thread 2](https://community.auth0.com/t/add-rate-limiting-and-cache-for-m2m-token-authentication-endpoints/75367/11)

I couldn't find anything related to caching the tokens in the Firebase documentation.

I'm trying to understand which Authentication workflows would be the easiest, cheapest and more secure to implement with Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would create a Firebase user after the getting their OAuth Token. For example, when using Google as the OAuth provider, the first half would be like:

[image]

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for complete diagram and flow.

After you get the response, you can call the [sign in user with OAuth credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential) that will create a user in Firebase Authentication. Thereafter, you can use Firebase's pair of access and refresh tokens to authenticate user on your backend. See [verify Firebase ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

A Firebase ID Token is a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) generally used as a [bearer token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#:%7E:text=Terminology%20Bearer%20Token%20A%20security,proof%2Dof%2Dpossession) that essentially means if you have the token, you have the permission to access given resources. You can just store the tokens on client's device and send them in API request and verify them every time. Only *caching* I can think of is storing a key-value pair where key is the token and value is user's ID so you don't have to verify the token every time but I  would just verify them.

---

When using Firebase Client SDKs, you don't have to deal with all this but just use built it methods like `signInWithPopup()` and Firebase will do this behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks! So this would be similar to the Diagram 2.

Also I just found this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353165/how-to-authenticate-login-with-firebase-admin-sdk-with-python) : "
Admin SDK should only be used in server-side applications. It doesn't support client-side operations like authenticating a user"

I thought it was possible to signing a user with the Admin SDK, but looking at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python) I couldn't find the signing function.

(The 1st diagram was from the Auth0)

Comment: @Sqdz correct, the 2nd diagram. (except there's no redis on frontend but local storage). Firebase SDK does that for you, no need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firebase auth you will use their web SDK (or one of the other client side SDKs) on client side and their admin SDK on server side. Firebase will handle the caching, tokens, etc. When you pass your request to the server the admin SDK can verify the auth before you process the request.